# How to call RxJava Observable without immediately subscribing?

Tags: java, multithreading, rx-java

I have a java method that returns a string template. I want to make 2 async call to a remote api, each call will return a number, then I want to compute the sum of these 2 numbers and put it into the template before returning it.

So I have this java code to achieve this task :

```
private Observable<Integer> createObservable() {
    Observable<Integer> obs = Observable.create(new OnSubscribe<Integer>() {

        public void call(Subscriber<? super Integer> t) {
            System.out.println("Call with thread : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            //FAKE CALL TO REMOTE API => THE THREAD IS SLEEPING DURING 4 SECCONDS
            try {
                Thread.sleep(4000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            t.onNext(new Random().nextInt(10));
            t.onCompleted();
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());
    
    return Observable
        .merge(obs, obs)
        .reduce(new Func2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
            
            public Integer call(Integer t1, Integer t2) {
                return t1 + t2;
            }
        });     
}

public String retrieveTemplate() {
    //I WANT TO START THE WORK OF THE OBSERVABLE HERE BUT I DON'T KNOW HOW TO DO IT
    
    //DO THINGS IN THE MAIN THREAD
    //HERE I JUST INITIALIZE A STRING BUT WE COULD IMAGINE I WOULD DO MORE THINGS
    String s = "The final Number is {0}";
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : the string is initialized");
    
    //I WAIT FOR THE OBSERVABLE RESULT HERE
    int result = createObservable().toBlocking().first();
    
    return MessageFormat.format(s, result);
}
```

The output of this code is correct (Two threads are created to call the remote api)

> main : the string is initialized
>
> Call with thread : RxNewThreadScheduler-1
>
> Call with thread : RxNewThreadScheduler-2
>
> The final Number is 2

I want to call the RxJava Observable at the begining of the method **retrieveTemplate** (in order to call the remote api as soon as possible) and wait for the result just before the call of **MessageFormat.format** but I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the whole creation process works, you may want to bind the whole computation together to subscription moment by transforming the source observable:

```
public Observable<String> retrieveTemplate() {
    return createObservable().map(result -> {
        String s = "The final Number is {0}";
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : the string is initialized");

        return MessageFormat.format(s, result);
    });
}
```

When you subscribe to the result observable of `retrieveTemplate` - you actually start the whole computation:

```
// some other place in the code
retrieveTemplate().subscribe(template -> doStuffWithTemplate(template))
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. Maybe my example is not well understandable but imagine in my method retrieveTemplate I want to do other operations that has nothing to do with the creation of my template (I should change the name of the method), so I want the observable start the work as soon as possible, continue to execute the code of the method and finally wait for the observable result and return it

Comment: This is indeed not clear. I don't think you can get a lot better than what I suggest. It starts when you subscribe. you can subscribe immediately if you want.

Comment: your solution doesn't allow me to return a result at the end of my method. You can imagine I want to call an Observable into a struts action. At the end of this action I have to return a string to indicate the name of the view which will be returned to the client. In this action I want to call an Observable and retrieve the result before returning the view to the client.

Comment: You'll have to block if you're committed to returning an actual result. Consider blocking with a `timeout`. I admit I don't fully understand what you're doing.